# Can I use NDSolve solutions into a third degree equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to take the solutions of a differential equation, like for example the harmonic oscillator, and pass them to a function in this way:

```
solo=NDSolve[{x''[t]+x[t]==0, x[0]==0, x'[1]==1}, x, {t,0,100}]; 

Tas=1/((x[t])^2+1);
Doit=Evaluate[Tas/.solo];
Plot[Doit,{t,0,20},PlotRange->{0,1}]
```

This works, meaning that I can see "Tas" (which is a Lorentzian) oscillating in time, as if I was constantly scanning the variable x back and forth, which is what I want to simulate.
Now I would like to do the same thing, but instead of "Tas" I wanna use a third degree equation, which has 3 solution parts (and which plotted together form also Lorentzian, but a distorted one, which is really the object I need to use). This object would be given by:

```
sol=DSolve[{1/((2x-y[x])^2+1)==y[x]},y,x];
```

The problem is that if now I simply put:

```
Doit=Evaluate[sol/.solo];
Plot[Doit,{t,0,20},PlotRange->{0,1}]
```

it gives me error as I think it doesn't understand that x in "sol" should take now the values x[t].

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way.

```
solo = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[1] == 1}, 
   x[t], {t, 0, 100}] // Flatten

x[t_] = x[t] /. %

Tas = 1/((x[t])^2 + 1);

Plot[Tas, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

And you get your first plot.  For your second part:

```
sol = DSolve[{1/((2 x - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y[x], x] // Flatten;

y[t_] = y[x] /. sol[[1]] /. x -> x[t]
```

As you pointed out `DSolve` produces 3 solutions.  I chose the first because it was the only one with real values to plot.

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[t]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

The breaks in the plot are due to some of the values being complex.  Alternately you could plot the real part.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[y[t]]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

with some values going negative.  If interested, you could plot the real and imaginary parts of the other two solutions also.

Comment: I'm totally surprised, that `DSolve[{1/((2 x - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y[x], x] ` gives a solution, athough it is not a differential equation. It does the same as Solve.

Comment: I was surprised too, but I like to use as much of the OP's code as I can, and `DSolve` worked, so I left it that way.

Comment: Great, thanks al lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make your `Tas` a function

```
ClearAll[y, x, t, Tas, f];
solo = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[1] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 100}];
Tas[f_, t_] := 1/((f[t])^2 + 1);
Plot[Tas[solo, t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 sol[x_] = y[x] /.(DSolve[{1/((2 x - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y[x], x][[1]]) (*pick first*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[Tas[sol, t], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]